# Java Merge Sort not working

Tags: java, sorting, merge, mergesort

Hi I have been working on getting the merge sort working, I have a complteted code but am not getting the right results... Here is my code and the results are "876323149" any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class MergeSort
{
  private static int[] local;  // for use in copying
  private static int[] a;
  public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  int[] test = {2,3,1,4,7,8,6,3,9};
  sort(test);}

  public static void sort(int[] orig)
  {
    int n = orig.length;
    local = new int[n];
    a = orig;
    recursiveSort(0, n-1);
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i ++){
    System.out.print(a[i]);
  }
  }

  private static void recursiveSort(int lo, int hi)
  {
    int mid =(hi + lo) / 2;
    if(hi-lo > 2){
      recursiveSort(lo, mid);
      recursiveSort(mid + 1, hi);
      merge(lo, mid + 1, hi);

    }      
  }

  private static void merge(int lo, int mid, int hi)
  {
    int d = lo;
    int b = mid + 1;
    int c = lo;
    for (int i = lo; i <= hi; i++) {
      local[i] = a[i];
    }
    while(d <= mid && b <= hi){
      if(local[d] > local[b]){
        a[c] = local[d];
        d++;}
      else{
        a[c] = local[b];
        b++;}
      c++;}
   while (d <= mid) {
      a[c] = local[d];
      c++;
      d++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: nope, just trying to figure out what the error is and I have tried comparing it to that website and is what I primarly based this code off of

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that lo is less than hi so that recursiveSort keeps sorting the different array recursively and doesn't try to sort an array of length <= 1. And more importantly mid must be set inside of this if statement every time the if statement is called

Here is the fix:

```
private static void recursiveSort(int lo, int hi)
{
if(lo < hi){
int mid =(hi + lo) / 2;

recursiveSort(lo, mid);
recursiveSort(mid + 1, hi);
merge(lo, mid + 1, hi);

}      
}
```